# jq: How to replace element in an array or add it if it doesn't exist

Tags: json, jq, upsert

Given the following json structure:

```
{
   "elements": [
      {
         "name": "disregard",
         "value": "me"
      },
      {
         "name": "foo",
         "value": "bar"
      },
      {
         "name": "dont-edit",
         "value": "me"
      }
   ]
}
```

What would be the appropriate `jq` query to replace the `value` of the `name: foo` element or create/add the element to the array, if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: I removed the elipsis, so it's valid JSON. I hope that's what you meant by *mre* @oguzismail. If you meant an actual query, well then I wouldn't be asking this question, if I could provide that. :)

Comment: You should also add an output example

Comment: @carlossless, I have edited your input so that it's a _valid JSON_

Comment: Carlossness - You're supposed also to show some attempt at a solution (even if it's not in jq). @Dmitry - It's still not valid JSON!

Comment: @peak, yes, it is, however, you probably don't see it yet, due to awaiting a peer review

Comment: @Dmitry - Right you are!  What a relief!!!

Comment: @carlossless, here's an alternative (non-jq) solution to your JSON query. 1. to update (replace) the `value` where `name": "foo"`: **`new_val='"BAR"'; <file.json jtc -w'[name]:<foo>[-1][value]' -u"$new_val"`**. 2. And this one is to insert (append) to the existing value: **`new_val='"BAR"'; <file.json jtc -w'[name]:<foo>[-1][value]' -mi"$new_val"`** I can elaborate on the tool usage if you like. (PS. I'm a developer of  `jtc` - unix tool for JSON processing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a safe if pedestrian solution:

```
.elements 
|=  (map(.name) | index("foo")) as $ix
    | if $ix 
      then .[$ix]["value"] = "BAR" 
      else . + [{name: "foo", value: "BAR"}]
      end
```

You might want to abstract away the `"foo"` and `"BAR"` bits:

#### upsert

```
# Input is assumed to be an array of {name:_, value:_} objects
def upsert($foo; $bar):
  (map(.name) | index($foo)) as $ix
  | if $ix then .[$ix]["value"] = $bar else . + [{name: $foo, value: $bar}] end;
```

Usage:

```
.elements |= upsert("foo"; "BAR")
```